# Unable to start Oryx - NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, classpath, apache-kafka, nosuchmethoderror, oryx

**Issue:**
When starting the oryx serving layer with the ALS example I get the following exception:

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener 
instance of class com.cloudera.oryx.lambda.serving.ModelManagerListener
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: kafka.admin.AdminUtils.topicExists(Lorg/I0Itec/zkclient/ZkClient;Ljava/lang/String;)Z
at com.cloudera.oryx.kafka.util.KafkaUtils.topicExists(KafkaUtils.java:93)
at com.cloudera.oryx.lambda.serving.ModelManagerListener.contextInitialized(ModelManagerListener.java:113)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4812)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5255)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

**Context:** I am running on CDH 5.7 in a docker container - all jars are in the expected location as compute-classpath suggests and kafka (0.8.2.0) is up and running with the topics that are needed:

```
**In dir opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/jars:**
commons-cli-1.2.jar                
kafka_2.10-0.8.2.0-kafka-1.4.0.jar
commons-collections-3.2.2.jar      
kafka-clients-0.8.2.0-kafka-1.4.0.jar
commons-configuration-1.6.jar      
protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar
hadoop-auth.jar
scala-library-2.11.8.jar
hadoop-common.jar
snappy-java-1.0.4.1.jar
hadoop-hdfs.jar
spark-examples-1.6.0-cdh5.7.0-hadoop2.6.0-cdh5.7.0.jar
htrace-core4-4.0.1-incubating.jar
zookeeper-copy.jar
```

**Config:**

```
kafka-brokers = "localhost:9092"
zk-servers = "localhost:2181"
hdfs-base = "hdfs:///user/example/Oryx"

oryx {
  id = "ALSExample"
  als {
    rescorer-provider-class = null
  }
  input-topic {
   broker = ${kafka-brokers}
    lock = {
  master = ${zk-servers}
  }
   }
  update-topic {
   broker = ${kafka-brokers}
  lock = {
    master = ${zk-servers}
  }
}
 batch {
   streaming {
  generation-interval-sec = 300
  num-executors = 4
  executor-cores = 8
  executor-memory = "4g"
}
update-class = "com.cloudera.oryx.app.batch.mllib.als.ALSUpdate"
 storage {
  data-dir =  ${hdfs-base}"/data/"
  model-dir = ${hdfs-base}"/model/"
 }
  ui {
   port = 4040
 }
   }
    speed { model-manager-class =            "com.cloudera.oryx.app.speed.als.ALSSpeedModelManager"
       ui {
    port = 4041
}
 }
 serving { model-manager-class =   "com.cloudera.oryx.app.serving.als.model.ALSServingModelManager"
   application-resources = "com.cloudera.oryx.app.serving,com.cloudera.oryx.app.serving.als"
   api {
     port = 8080
}
 }
 }
```

**Example start command:**
`/oryx-run.sh serving --conf als-example.conf --app-jar oryx-serving-2.1.2.jar`
or
`/oryx-run.sh serving --conf als-example.conf --app-jar example.jar`

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated :-)

Comment: Additional: this is running oryx 2.1.2 release version and there is only an issue with the serving layer.

Comment: Added issue to Github for visibility (and another potential issue occurring with the latest build): https://github.com/OryxProject/oryx/issues/289

Comment: I will reply at https://github.com/OryxProject/oryx/issues/289

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copying the conclusion back here: CDH 5.7 ships with and requires Apache Kafka 0.9. So, it will be necessary to use Oryx 2.2.x, which supports 0.9, with 5.7. It will be release shortly.